# Can Eller's Algorithm or Recursive Division be used to solve a maze

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, maze, array-algorithms

I am trying to solve a maze using Eller's Algorithm and Recursive Division, Although I know that these two Algorithms can be used to generate a maze but is it possible to solve one using either Eller's Algorithm or Recursive Division?

I have tried to solve a maze through Eller's Algorithm by making some modifications but I have not achieved any satisfactory results, and as for as recursive division is concerned I am unable to find any information to solve through it online.

Comment: It's very unclear how maze generation algorithms would be useful in solving a maze. Please edit your post with more details on what you're attempting (what are the modifications in question?)

Comment: The answer is no.  Maze generation algorithms are for generating mazes, and are of no use whatsoever in solving them.